# How do I contribute to a Git-hosted project on Google Code?

Tags: git, google-code

I'm rather new to Git and in particular Git-hosting on Google Code. My question is, how do I contribute to a Git-hosted project on Google Code.

I'd made a clone of the original project. What next? And how do I send a pull request to the original-project.

I want to know the workflow and Git-commands.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with any other project offering a git repository (except for github that has internal fork and pull request functions) you either publish your modified repo and send a link and a branch name to the authors of the original software, or use `git-format-patch` and/or `git-send-email` to format and send patches for each added commit to the authors.